# Is it inefficient (data transfer ratewise) to pass big dictionary to updateChildValues even when only key value pair needs an update?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Say I have a user profile dictionary with various key value such as:

```
["email" : "Anon@gmail.com", "age": 30, "displayName" : "John Doe", "Birthday" : ..., etc]
```

If the user update's the display name to "John Appleseed", ideally I would only pass

```
["displayName" : "John Appleseed"]
```

by doing this:

```
ref.child("users").child("userID1").updateChildValues(["displayName" : "John Appleseed"])
```

However, instead of sending the dictionary only with the updates needed, is it ok to send the whole user profile dictionary with the update information?

```
ref.child("users").child("userID1").updateChildValues(["email" : "Anon@gmail.com", "age": 30, "displayName" : "John Appleseed", "Birthday" : ..., etc])
```

Firebase database has free GB transferred limit.

I'm' wondering if Firebase has under the hood optimization to send only the

`["displayName" : "John Appleseed"]`

from the big dictionary, so that only the real update portion triggers the server update and reduces the amount of data transferred.